# Arch - VirtualBox - Use mounted ISO

Tags: virtualbox, mount, iso-image, arch-linux

I've an *.img file, that can't be converted to *.iso, because its a multi-session disk.
So I simply changed the file ending to .iso.

Now, I am able to mount it using the following command:
mount -o loop dvd.iso /media/iso

BUT: When I try to use this iso in VirtualBox, it fails!
Is there a way to mount the iso file as a drive, and then use it in VirtualBox?

Comment: What OS are you running in vb, or is this a boot disk?

Comment: There is no OS at the moment. It´s a Win7 DVD-image, so I want to install Win7.

Comment: When you do ```mount -o loop``` it creates a loopback device that represents the ISO, and then mounts the loopback.  Given that you can mount the iso in linux, I guess vb is using a different method.  Try mounting in linux, then do ```losetup -a``` to find out which ```/dev/loop``` it created (```/dev/loop0``` for example).  Then when adding the cdrom device to your vm, use the ```/dev/loop``` device instead of the iso directly.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for this tip, but this does not seem to work. "The medium '/dev/loop0' can't be used as the requested device type". I've also tested it with a normal ISO, but it didn't work. Do you have another idea?

Comment: What was the requested device type?  It should be added as a physical device.

Comment: In the newest version, I can't find a way to add a specific device type, there is only the possibility to use an ISO or one of the physical drives.

Comment: So which did you select?  It should be a physical device and then the /dev/loop0

Comment: The loop device is not displayed in the list, so I can´t select it. The only way I can select it, is to click on "select media" and then click on the /dev/loop0 file, but then I get the error message I mentioned...

Comment: Ok, perhaps grabbing straws here, but the mounted loopback may well be the first session in the .img, so you may be able to convert it to an iso by doing ```dd if=/dev/loop0 of=dvd.iso bs=1M``` Then try to use the resulting iso file as a cdrom for the vm (just try mounting it first to make sure it has sane content).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using dd, with an output as .iso from the mounted image... ie

```
dd if=/where/you/have/.img/mounted of=/~/image/.iso
```

then use the new .iso image with virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

Try to use losetup command.

```
losetup /dev/loop0 yourfile.iso
```

It link your iso file to a loopdevice.

Answer (score 0):

virtualbox does not accept iso9660 format for iso images so first convert it to raw image:

```
mount -t iso9660 -o loop /your/iso9660.iso /some/where

dd if=/dev/loop0 of=/raw_image.iso
```

then use the new image.iso with virtualbox.